# Devices are not supported by this Flutter project

Tags: flutter, macos, flutter-web

Theres is a project made on flutter which i have to continue, it's my first time using flutter, basically i already downloaded the project from github and installed the dependencies as well, but when i try to run the project this message apperars:

```
No supported devices connected.

The following devices were found, but are not supported by this project:

macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-x64

Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 108.0.5359.124

If you would like your app to run on macos or web, consider running `flutter create .` to generate projects for these platforms.
```

I don't want to create another project, i just need to run this one.

I'm using VS Code and i was told at the bottom right corner there is a button for choosing a device. When i click on it this shows up:

[enter imaImage description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQJix.png)

I'm using a mac PC

I searched on internet but still dont know what to do, i watched lot of videos explaining how to start a new project of flutter but it's not the same for my project, obviously i'm missing something